# How to rewrite Magento community iwd opc controller

Tags: php, xml, magento

This is my first post.

I'm trying to rewrite the controller with path **/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/controllers/CouponController.php**

following these steps:

Step 1: create the same folder structure at 
**/app/code/local/Company/IWD/Opc/controllers/CouponController.php**

Step 2: rewrite controller extending the original:

```
 <?php

   require('IWD/Opc/controllers/CouponController.php');

   class Company_IWD_Opc extends IWD_Opc_CouponController
   {
      public function couponPostAction(){
       Mage::log("Metodo redefinido");
       $responseData = array();
    /**
     * No reason continue with empty shopping cart
     */
      if (!$this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
      }
       die('Hello world!');
     }
   } 
 ?>
```

Step 3: **/app/code/local/Company/IWD/Opc/etc/config.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
<modules>
    <Company_IWD_Opc>
        <version>0.0.1</version> 
    </Company_IWD_Opc>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <opc>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company__IWD_Opc before="IWD_Opc">Company_IWD_Opc</<Company__IWD_Opc>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </onepagecheckout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Step 4: define **\app\etc\modules\Company_IWD_Opc.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <config>
        <modules>
          <Company_IWD_Opc>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
               <IWD_Opc />
            </depends>
          </Company_IWD_Opc>
       </modules>
     </config>
```

Step 5: Clear cache

Step 6: Test the controller using test.php file (from other post). It seems that the module is perfectly installed but the new controller don't work, the function's code isn't executed

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL^E_STRICT);
  include 'app/Mage.php';
   Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
  Mage::app();

  $origDir = Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Company_IWD_Opc').DS;
   require_once $origDir.'CouponController.php';

$controller = new Company_IWD_Opc_CouponController(
  Mage::app()->getRequest(),    //required constructor arg
  Mage::app()->getResponse()    //required constructor arg
);

echo get_class($controller);

$router = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRouter('standard');
/* @var $router Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard */

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($router);
$modules = $reflection->getProperty('_modules');
$modules->setAccessible(true);

var_dump($modules->getValue($router));
```

**Output:**
Company_IWD_Opc_CouponControllerarray(58) { ["core"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Mage_Core" } ["directory"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "Mage_Directory" } ["cms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Mage_Cms" } ["customer"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(20) "Company_Custom_Customer" [1]=> string(13) "Mage_Customer" } ["catalog"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(29) "Smartwave_Ajaxcatalog_Catalog" [1]=> string(12) "Mage_Catalog" } ["catalogsearch"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(35) "Smartwave_Ajaxcatalog_CatalogSearch" [1]=> string(18) "Mage_CatalogSearch" } ["sales"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "Company_Custom_Sales" [1]=> string(10) "Mage_Sales" } ["shipping"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Mage_Shipping" } ["paygate"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Mage_Paygate" } ["checkout"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(16) "IWD_Opc_Checkout" [1]=> string(20) "Company_Custom_Checkout" [2]=> string(13) "Mage_Checkout" } ["paypal"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Mage_Paypal" } ["poll"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Mage_Poll" } ["review"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Mage_Review" } ["tag"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Mage_Tag" } ["wishlist"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Mage_Wishlist" } ["paypaluk"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Mage_PaypalUk" } ["media"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Mage_Media" } ["giftmessage"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Mage_GiftMessage" } ["contacts"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(20) "Company_Custom_Contacts" [1]=> string(13) "Mage_Contacts" } ["sendfriend"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "Mage_Sendfriend" } ["rss"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Mage_Rss" } ["productalert"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Mage_ProductAlert" } ["api"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Mage_Api" } ["oauth"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Mage_Oauth" } ["authorizenet"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Mage_Authorizenet" } ["captcha"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Mage_Captcha" } ["centinel"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Mage_Centinel" } ["newsletter"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "Mage_Newsletter" } ["downloadable"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Mage_Downloadable" } ["persistent"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "Mage_Persistent" } ["xmlconnect"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "Mage_XmlConnect" } ["brainsins"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Brainsins_Recommender" } ["smartecommerce"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "Brainsins_Smartecommerce" } ["sitemap"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Creare_DynamicSitemap" } ["cupondescuento"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "Digitaldot_Cupondescuento" } ["doofinder"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "Doofinder_Feed" } ["custom"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Company_Custom" } ["applycoupon"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Company_Applycoupon" } ["valoraciones"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Company_Valoraciones" } ["etiquetaspersonalizadas"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "Company_Etiquetaspersonalizadas" } ["cuadrospersonalizadas"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "Company_Cuadrospersonalizadas" } ["onepage"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(29) "Company_IWD_Opc_CouponController" [1]=> string(7) "IWD_Opc" } ["atributos"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "Company_Atributos" } ["ajaxcatalog"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Smartwave_Ajaxcatalog" } ["regalospersonalizados"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "Company_Regalospersonalizados" } ["iwdextensions"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "IWD_All" } ["serviredpro"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "Interactiv4_ServiRedPro" } ["solarium"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "JeroenVermeulen_Solarium" } ["dailydeal"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "Magegiant_Dailydeal" } ["moneybookers"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "Phoenix_Moneybookers" } ["ajaxcart"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "Smartwave_Ajaxcart" } ["filterproducts"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "Smartwave_Filterproducts" } ["megamenu"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "Smartwave_Megamenu" } ["quickview"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "Smartwave_QuickView" } ["ajaxify"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Sp_Ajaxify" } ["infinitescroll2"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "Strategery_Infinitescroll2" } ["widgentologin"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "Widgento_Login" } ["ordercancel"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Yumba_OrderCancel" } }

¿Any solution? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share how you're testing the controller?

Comment: Your `functionName` won't be accessible from the frontend of Magento because it's not an Action. You'd need to name it `functionnameAction` to be able to see if via `magento.com/module/controller/functionname`

Comment: That's a ridiculously convoluted way to test a controller rewrite, seriously. Just test it from your browser!

Comment: @RobbieAverill I have tested the controller by all the ways, this it's the last. ¿Do you know how to solve the problem? I'm noob in Magento